# Eliminar cuenta con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero eliminar una cuenta registrada pero esta tiene ya unas transacciones registradas que estan asociada a esa cuenta
[image: Vista de las cuentas]
y en ella se encutran transacciones ya agregadas
[image: Vista de transacciones]
al hacer el llamado de eliminar tengo en el controlador de Cuentas:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
      Cuenta::find($id)->delete();
      return redirect()->route('cuentas.index');
    }
```

y las migraciones que tengo son:
Tabla cuentas:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cuentas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('Nombre');
            $table->string('Descripcion');
            $table->integer('Interes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

tabla transacciones:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transaccions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('Cantidad');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->bigInteger('cuenta_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cuenta_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('cuentas')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

y quiero borrar la cuenta con transacciones incluidas, pero al darle eliminar me da el error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`creditex`.`transaccions`, CONSTRAINT `transaccions_cuenta_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`cuenta_id`) REFERENCES `cuentas` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `cuentas` where `id` = 1)

Comment: Puedes utilizar softdeletes, de esta forma el registro permanece para futuros reportes

Answer (score 0):

No vas a poder eliminar ya que esta activo la llave foranea, si de todas formas quieres hacerlo tienes que desactivar en tu `BD`.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Asi te dejará eliminarlos, otra forma es usando `CASCADE`, esto elimina todas los registros que dependen de la que vas a eliminar

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
  ->references('id')->on('users')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: De hecho si revisas lo segundo que propones ya lo tiene en su migración